# File not found exception in existing file on Digital Ocean space with laravel

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3, digital-ocean, digital-ocean-spaces

I have uploaded a file using Laravel s3 driver configured for Digital Ocean space. Now I want to download the file using an api request. The code for the download is:

```
return \response()->download(Storage::disk('do')->url($user->cv), $user->name);
```

It gives me an error response saying

```
The file "https://lms3.fra1.digitaloceanspaces.com/answers/3/ygcFuQfmVgdcxWRteE3hTlF0CuntsycSQmuDystT.pdf"
```

But the file actually exists and you can check this link.
What is wrong with this code?

Comment: If I had to guess without seeing much code, I would think it's due to permissions not being set properly. Also, you don't need a `\ ` before `response()`, since `response()` is a global function.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and I just found a (shitty) workaround. Or at least a way to get Laravel to find the file.

`php artisan cache:clear`